# Filtering items response in vimeo api

Tags: vimeo, vimeo-api

I am using the /users/id/projects/id/items URI to get all the subfolders of a folder in Vimeo API. This is the response I get. Is there any way to filter this response during the GET call so that I only get folders and not videos?

Image attached of console logged response:
[image: Image attached of console logged response]

Comment: The purple syntax coloring looks good, but readers might perhaps rather prefer formatted Code **Text** rather than an image for being able to copy and paste and run your code o data type before posting an Answer

Comment: Any updates on this? I've ran into the same problem. I tried the filter query parameter but it's not working for me.